# RDP Server - Last Logon Time of All RDP Users

Tags: windows-server-2012, login

I am attempting to get a list of "last logon time" of "all users" on Windows Server 2012. This is 'not' for Active Directory; This server's purpose is only for RDP Connections/RDP Logins. I currently only know of how to list a single user login, which is:

`net user username | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"`

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.